# Java Android MVVM - how to send a variable from Repository back to activity?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-asynctask

I can get **rowId value** using an ASynctask in **onPostExecute method** ,I am trying to send the value back to the activity so it can be stored and used later so how to do that.

Activity :

```
Note note = new Note(userId, therapistId, automaticThoughtString,  distortions, challengeThoughtString, alternativeThoughtString, postedWorkout);
             noteViewModel.insert(note).observe(WorkoutAutomaticThoughtActivity.this, new Observer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Long cbtId) {

                    sqCbtId = cbtId;
                    Log.d(TAG, "AutomaticThought" + sqCbtId);
                }
            });
```

Viewmodel :

```
 public LiveData<Long> insert (Note note) {
    return repository.insert(note);  
}
```

Repository :

```
    public MutableLiveData<Long> insert(Note note) {
    final MutableLiveData<Long> cbtId = new MutableLiveData<>();
    new InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao, cbtId).execute(note);
    return cbtId;
```

Async :

```
 public InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao, MutableLiveData<Long> cbtId) {
    this.noteDao = noteDao;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
    sqCbtId = noteDao.insert(notes[0]);
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    getCbtId(sqCbtId);
    Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecuteAsync: " + sqCbtId);
}

public void getCbtId(long cbtId) {
    sqCbtId = cbtId;
}
```

CbtId is being capture correctly in the log.d but its not sending back to the activity. I think it may be something to do with the constructor in the Async task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your insert method

```
public MutableLiveData<Long> insert(Note note) {
 final MutableLiveData<Long> id = new MutableLiveData<>();
 new InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao, id).execute(note); 
 return id;
}
```

Modify `InsertNoteAsyncTask` construct and receive the `id`. Now modify the onPostExecute method and set the `id` value

```
   class InsertNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Long> {
    private NoteDao noteDao;
    private MutableLiveData<Long> id;
     public InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao, MutableLiveData<Long> id) {
        this.noteDao = noteDao;
        this.id = id;
     }

     @Override
     protected Long doInBackground(Note... notes) {
        long sqCbtId = noteDao.insert(notes[0]);
        return sqCbId;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Long sqCbtId) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        id.setValue(sqCbtId); 
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecuteAsync: " + sqCbtId);
     }
    }
```

Now in ViewModel return the MutableLiveData and observe it in Activity. for eg:

```
public LiveData<Long> insertNote(Note note) {
  return noteRepository.insert(note);
}
```

Now in `Activity`, you can observe the change in the `LiveData`:

```
viewModel.insertNote(Note).observe(this,
        new Observer<Long>() {
          @Override
          public void onChanged(Long id) {
            // do whatever you want with the id
          }
        });
```

Comment: I can't ge the repository part to work: I changed the constructor to this:  private InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao, Long cbtId) {
            this.noteDao = noteDao;
            this.cbtId = cbtId;
However the "this.cbtId" is in red, it wont accept it, so the first insert method is now also in red and the onResponse has no cbtId.setvalue method avaialble

Comment: I updated the code in the question to try and resemble your suggestion. I think the constructor in the Async is not done correctly though.

Comment: I have updated the `InsertNoteAsyncTask` . It should work for you now.